# Reference for Async LINQ in EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I used to include `System.Data.Entity` back in EF 6. Reading some StackOverflow posts, they recommend me to include Microsoft.Data.Entity but that reference doesn't exist.

Which is the reference (using) that I need to include so FirstOrDefaultAsync() works in Entity Framework Core?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's contained in `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: Perfect! That's it!